# Using ng-disabled with input select2

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I'm trying to enable a select2 field only when another combobox is selected. This works fine with textbox, normal input or even simple select elements, but when I try to use ng-disabled with a select2 that uses an Ajax call, it doesn't work.

Here is part of my code:

```
<section class="col col-sm-4">
    <label class="label" data-localize="Tipo de Participante"></label>
    <select id="select_tipo_participante" name="select_tipo_participante" ng-model="filtros.F_ID_TIPO_PARTICIPANTE.Valor"
      class="select2" data-placeholder="Selecione..."
      ng-disabled="filtros.F_ID_USUARIO.Valor == null">
        <option value="null" data-localize="Selecione uma opção"></option>
        <option ng-repeat="tipo in dados_listas.tipos_participante" value="{{tipo.ID_TIPO_PARTICIPANTE}}">
            {{tipo.NM_TIPO_PARTICIPANTE}}
        </option>
    </select>
</section>

<section class="col col-sm-4">
    <label class="label" data-localize="Novo Usuário"></label>
    <input name="select_novo_usuario" id="select_novo_usuario" ng-model="filtros.F_ID_USUARIO.Valor" ng-disabled="filtros.F_ID_TIPO_PARTICIPANTE.Valor == null"/>
</section>
<section class="col col-sm-12">
    <label class="label" data-localize="Justificativa"></label>
    <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" name="justificativa_redesignacao" ng-model="DS_JUSTIFICATIVA" ng-disabled="filtros.F_ID_TIPO_PARTICIPANTE.Valor == null"></textarea>
```

I want to keep the second element (id="select_novo_usuario") disabled until the previous one is selected.

The textarea using ng-disabled works just fine.

Here is my ajax call:

```
    $("#select_novo_usuario").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 4,
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: localize.localizeText('tooltip_select_interessado'),
    ajax: {
        url: BACKEND_URL + 'usuario_interessado',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        quietMillis: 50,
         data: function (term) {
                var filter = 'NM_USUARIO,like,' + term;
            return {
                filters: filter,
                filter_id_interessado: 'ID_USUARIO,notin,teste.teste'
            };
        },
        results: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.NM_USUARIO,
                        slug: item.NM_USUARIO,
                        id: item.ID_USUARIO
                    }
                })
            };
        },
    },
});

$("#select_novo_usuario").on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
            $scope.filtros.F_ID_USUARIO.Valor = e.val;
        });
    });
});
```

How can I get it working?

Comment: try ng-disabled="!filtros.F_ID_TIPO_PARTICIPANTE.Valor"

Comment: It didn't work @tpie

Comment: if you console.log($scope.filtros.F_ID_TIPO_PARTICIPANTE.Valor),
what do you get?  Before you touch the select.

Comment: I get _null_ @tpie, and to verify, I've added the ng-disabled to a textarea with the same filtros.F_ID_TIPO_PARTICIPANTE.Valor and it works, it appears disabled until I touch the select.

Comment: it should make a difference then.  If one is disabled, the other should be too.

Comment: see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't be able to get it working using ng-disabled, so I did it in the my .js file, making the select I want to disable respond to the $watch of the previous one.
Here is my code as a sampe:

```
$scope.$watch('filtros.F_ID_TIPO_PARTICIPANTE.Valor', function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
if(newVal != null) {
    $('#select_novo_usuario').select2("enable", true);
    $('#select_novo_usuario').select2("val", "");
}
$('#select_novo_usuario').select2("enable", false);
$('#select_novo_usuario').select2("val", "");});
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have it set up correctly.

Try removing `ng-disabled="filtros.F_ID_USUARIO.Valor == null` on the select
They are disabling **each other**, it appears.

If I read your code correctly, the input is not populated until something is selected, correct?  Since they appear to be disabling each other, it seems neither one should be enabled.

If the select is untouched, it should be set to null.  Both your ng-disabled values on your input and textarea should be returning null.  Here is a plunker demonstrating that:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/muIOwdi09YUqvkFoTHPx)

Both the input and textarea are disabled until you select an item in the select.

Comment: The ng-disabled doesn't seems to work with select2 in my setup, even though it works fine with other select elements, or any other element. The way I found to get it working was setting it in my .js file. I've posted my sample as the answer. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

ng-disabled not seem working with Select2

try this one :

```
//As of Select2 4.1, they've removed support for .enable
$("select").prop("disabled", true); 
// instead of $("select").enable(false);
```